# What does Robinson's overspill lemma tell us?

Tags: logic, model-theory, peano-axioms, nonstandard-models

My reference is Richard Kaye's *Models of Peano Arithmetic*, section 6.1.

I am wondering what Robinson's overspill lemma actually tells us, and a bit of motivation on it. I have heard of it before, and it is described as of 'utmost importance', but the statement has me confused. Kaye motivates the lemma with the following paragraph:

> Suppose that $I$ is a proper cut of $M\vDash PA$, i.e. $I$ is not equal to the domain of $M$; then $I$ is not a *definable* subset of $M$; for if $\overline a\in M$ and $\varphi(x,\overline a)$ is an $\mathscr{L}_A$-formula with
>   $$I=\{b\in M: M\vDash\varphi(b,\overline a)\},$$
>   then $M\vDash\varphi(0,\overline a)\wedge\forall x(\varphi(x,\overline a)\rightarrow\varphi(x+1,\overline a))$, since $I$ is non-empty and is closed under the successor function, and so by induction in $M$, $M\vDash\forall x\varphi(x,\overline a)$, contradicting the assumption that $I$ is a proper cut. The *overspill lemma*, due to Abraham Robinson, essentially says just this.

The statement of the lemma seems to say that there is some non-standard $c>I$ such that $\varphi$ holds for all $x\le c$, and the proof uses that $I$ cannot be definable.

> *Lemma 6.1 (Overspill).* Let $M\vDash PA$ be non-standard and let $I$ be a proper cut of $M$. Suppose $\overline a\in M$ and $\varphi(x,\overline a)$ is an $\mathscr L_A$-formula such that $$M\vDash\varphi(b,\overline a)\;\text{for all}\;b\in I.$$
>   Then there is $c>I$ in $M$ such that $$M\vDash\forall x\le c\varphi(x,\overline a).$$

The proof is brief, saying that if the assumptions were true, but the conclusion false, then $I$ would be defined by the formula
$$\forall y<x\varphi(y,\overline a).$$

If I understand correctly, this follows from the following reasoning. If $x\in I$ then the formula holds, since $y<x\in I\implies y\in I$ by definition of a cut, and $M\vDash\varphi(b,\overline a)$ for all $b\in I$. Conversely, if $x$ satisfies $\forall y<x\varphi(y,\overline a)$, then either $x\in I$; or otherwise $x>I$ and there is a $c>I$ such that $c<x$ and so $M\vDash\forall x\le c\varphi(x,\overline a)$.

I wonder though what the 'true significance' of this lemma is. It seems like a coincidence derived from how we defined cuts... and I cannot see how it could be relevant or useful. Is there an intuitive way to think of this $\varphi$ or $c$? The way I am imagining it is that $\varphi(b,\overline a)$ is true for all of $I$, then it remains true beyond $I$ for a while (before possibly 'becoming' untrue at at some point).

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your understanding of the result, and of its proof, is correct. So why is it *important*?

My personal favorite set of applications come from trying to understand the *standard system* of a nonstandard $M\models PA$: $SS(M)$ is the set of sets $X$ of (standard) natural numbers such that, for some $c\in M$, $$X=\{k\in\mathbb{N}: M\models\underline{p_k}\vert c\}$$ (where $\underline{k}$ is the numeral standing for the standard natural number $k$, and $p_k$ denotes the $k$th prime).

---

Let's start with an easy application: in any nonstandard model of $PA$, definable sets of true natural numbers are coded by nonstandard elements. That is: suppose $M\models PA$ is nonstandard, and $\varphi$ is a formula of arithmetic with some parameters from $M$ and one free variable. Then there is a (nonstandard) $c\in M$ such that for all *standard* $k$, we have $$M\models \underline{p_k}\vert c\iff M\models\varphi(\underline{k}).$$

Why? Well, say that $m\in M$ is *nice* if there is (in $M$) a $c$ such that *for all $k<m$*, $p_k\vert c$ iff $\varphi(k)$. Note that this definition takes place entirely in $M$: no reference to standard elements is made. Well, clearly every standard $m$ is nice, so by overspill some nonstandard $m$ is nice; but then take a witnessing $c$.

---

Here's a more interesting one: suppose $M$ is nonstandard. Then there is a consistent completion of $PA$ which is in $SS(M)$, *even if $M$ thinks $PA$ is inconsistent!* Why?

Well, first note that we can reason in $PA$ about finite binary strings, and sentences and proofs in the language of arithmetic. So let's consider the following object: $T$ is the set of $\sigma\in 2^{<\mathbb{N}}$ such that the set $$PA\cup\{\varphi_n: \sigma(n)=1\}\cup\{\neg\varphi_n: \sigma(n)=0\}$$ does not have a proof of $0=1$ using fewer than $\vert\sigma\vert$-many symbols (where $\{\varphi_n: n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is some reasonable enumeration of the sentences of arithmetic). $T$ is appropriately definable, and indeed *absolute*: if $\sigma$ is in the true $T$, then $\sigma$ is also in $T^M$ for any nonstandard model $M$.

Now, in reality $T$ has infinite paths, since $PA$ is in fact consistent. So by overspill, $T^M$ has a node of nonstandard length! Let $\sigma$ be such a node; since the set of $k$ such that $\sigma(k)=1$ is definable, by the above point we get some $c\in M$ such that for all *standard* $k$, $p_k\vert c\iff \sigma(k)=1$. But then the element of $SS(M)$ coded by $c$ is (the set of Goedel numbers of) a consistent completion of $PA$. (Why is it *consistent*? Well, no contradiction can be proved using $\vert\sigma\vert$-many symbols - but $\vert\sigma\vert$ is infinite!)

*Incidentally, a similar argument can be used to show that [any model $M$ of ZFC contains an element which is a model of ZFC, even if $M$ thinks ZFC is inconsistent](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/51754/clearing-misconceptions-defining-is-a-model-of-zfc-in-zfc/51786#51786).*

---

Now, these two examples illustrate an important point about the value of overspill. The first example, honestly, would be clearer if we ignored overspill and just used induction. The second, however, has a nice intuitive picture via overspill (take a node of nonstandard length!), whereas the induction version (in my opinion) obscures the intuition. The true value of overspill is in "repackaging" a certain class of inductive arguments in a more intuitive way. It is particularly useful when we're juggling between "internal" concepts (elements of $M$) and "external" concepts (the set of naturals coded by an element of $M$).

Comment: I wanted to come back to this after doing some more reading. Thanks for the answer, these are nice examples! :-)

Comment: @Noah, I don't understand your third section. I can see that we have a node $\sigma$ of nonstandard length in $T^M$ such that $M \models \Sigma(\sigma) := (\text{PA}_\sigma \text{ does not have a proof of } 0 = 1 \text{ using fewer than } |\sigma|\text{-many symbols}$), where $\text{PA}_\sigma = PA\cup\{\varphi_n: \sigma(n)=1\}\cup\{\neg\varphi_n: \sigma(n)=0\}$. But this is within the model $M$. How do you get from here to "the element coded by $c$ is a consistent completion of $\text{PA}$", which is a claim in $\mathbb{N}$? And what is a completion?

Comment: The formula $\Sigma(\sigma)$ is $\Sigma_1$ right, not $\Delta_1$? So absoluteness is only in one direction. But even if it were $\Delta_1$, we could only say $\mathbb{N} \models \Sigma(\sigma) \Leftrightarrow M \models \Sigma(\sigma)$ for $\sigma \in 2^{<\omega}$. But we consider $\sigma$ restricted to the whole $\mathbb{N}$, not just a finite subset. So I guess this is proved not by means of absoluteness? Or maybe I'm confused! Thanks, a lot in advance!

Comment: @Jori No, $\Sigma(\sigma)$ is $\Delta_1$ since there are only finitely many proofs using a bounded number of symbols - only bounded quantifiers are involved.

Comment: But that's really beside the point. Suppose the standard part of $\mathsf{PA}_\sigma$ were inconsistent. Any standard proof $\pi$ of $\perp$ from the standard part of $\mathsf{PA}_\sigma$ exists in $M$ and is seen there to be a proof of $\perp$ from $\mathsf{PA}_\sigma$. But $\pi$, being standard, can only use finitely many symbols - but $M$ thinks that there is no contradiction in $\mathsf{PA}_\sigma$ using $\le\vert\sigma\vert$-many symbols. So the standard part of $\mathsf{PA}_\sigma$ is consistent (and it's clearly a completion of $\mathsf{PA}$).

Comment: @Noah Thanks, I think I get it. I was confused because I thought it was an absoluteness argument, but rather you use a direct observation about the meaning of "proof" in the standard model versus in a nonstandard model; that the latter is more encompassing. Correct?

Comment: With regard to $\Sigma(\sigma)$ being $\Delta_0$, I think I can see why, but you need the formula enumerating $\varphi_n$ and $\text{PA}$ to be $\Delta_0$ as well, right? Which is OK, because you can do the enumeration primitively recursive?

Comment: Finally, does what counts as a proof in the nonstandard model $M$ not depend a lot on how exactly you define the proof predicate? It doesn't matter here, but in general is this a significant issue? Again, thanks a lot Noah. You're a great help to logic enthusiasts of all levels!

Comment: @Jori Yes-ish to all points. In general, any "non-silly" definition of proof will give the same theory - but there **are indeed** times where this matters a lot, e.g. in the context of [self-verifying theories](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jsl/1183746459). I just tend to stay away from such theories, and then things work out fine as long as you don't deliberately break them. It's worth saying that there is some stuff known about what conditions a provability predicate (or etc.) must satisfy in order to behave well, I just don't know a lot about that; I usually live at $I\Sigma_1$ or above.